# How to use variable outside of foreach (Smarty)?

Tags: smarty

I've the following code

```
 {foreach name=cats from=$category->subcategories item=n}

{$a = $smarty.foreach.cats.index} 
                 {/foreach}
```

How to use `$a` variable outside of foreach?
For example

```
    {foreach from=$system item=n}


    <li>
        <a href="catalog/{$n->url}" category_id="{$n->id}">
            <b>{$a}</b>
        </a>

    </li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you first do a foreach of an array just to get $a and then use it in another foreach? That doesn't makes any sense. Can you show us the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try below for variable "a" assignment:

```
{foreach name=cats from=$category->subcategories item=n}
    {assign var=a value=$smarty.foreach.cats.index}
{/foreach}
```